# debugger-ui\debuggerWorker can not relove

Tags: react-native

```
[Sun Jul 19 2020 20:01:28.477]  LOG      JavaScript logs will appear in your browser console      
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1096:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have this error. Code is running but UI is not visible in the emulator. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app on emulator and re install it using following command.

Android:

```
expo client:install:android
```

IOS:

```
expo client:install:ios
```